# Box-shadow issue when use bourbon in rails 3.2 with twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, bourbon

I have a file called `bootstrap_and_overides.css.scss` contains style for my app. Now i installed bourbon gem to use sass mixin. But when i used add-ons buttons, sites had error:

```
Mixin box-shadow takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.  
(in   /home/hkthanh89/rails_apps/online_test_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

This is my `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "bourbon";  
@import "bootstrap_and_overrides";
```

I defined a link in my view file:

```
<p>
  <%= link_to "Add new course", new_course_path, class: "new_resource" %>
</p>
```

My bootstrap style file don't have any box-shadow. I defined new_resource class in my bootstrap style:

```
/* Buttons */  
.new_resource {
@include button(pill, #3FB344)
}
```

I don't know why error with mixin box-shadow. Can anybody help? Thanks so much !

Comment: Aren't you missing a semicolon after that CSS @include line?

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding Bootstrap to your app?  Maybe this is a conflict with Bootstrap's own button mixin?

I'm using bootstrap via this gem in my rails 3.2 app:

https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails

So I can only use the specific things from bootstrap that I care about.  For instance I'm
using Neat ( Bourbon's complimenting responsive grid ) so I don't want to bring in Bootstrap's layout or grid mixin's.

If you need some examples of how I have things configured let me know.  I am able to use bourbon's button mixin without error.

Comment: Bootstrap has a `buttonBackground` mixin, but I don't think it has one called `button`.